# Why '*.exe's in Python installation?

Tags: python

Just out of curiosity I executed following command and I was surprised to see MS Windows executables in the Python installation directory.

```
    20:36:46 nixlap [~] $ locate -i -r exe$
    [snipped]
    /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/setuptools/cli.exe
    /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/setuptools/gui.exe
    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/cli.exe
    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/gui.exe
    /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/wininst-6.0.exe
    /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/wininst-7.1.exe
    /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/wininst-8.0.exe
    /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/wininst-9.0-amd64.exe
    /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/wininst-9.0.exe
    /usr/lib/tomboy/Tomboy.exe
    /usr/share/mono/MonoGetAssemblyName.exe
    /usr/share/pyshared/setuptools/cli.exe
    /usr/share/pyshared/setuptools/gui.exe
```

Why do we need these `.exe` on Ubuntu installation? Particularly talking about the `exe`s in Python package.

I just don't like the files ending in `.exe`.

I can understand that banshee, tomboy, gbrainy use 'mono' but why can't they just name it something other than `.exe`.

Comment: Probably cause it saves them time and energy when porting the app to other platforms(in this case MS).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to `dpkg` and the [packages website](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/amd64/python2.7-dev/filelist) these are part of the `python2.7-dev` package. This is not installed by default.

I believe they include the Windows installers to allow people to create portable self-contained projects more easily (without having to hunt down the current version installer) but I could be wrong.

If you want to know for sure (or suggest these files get removed) you can find several contact methods on the [package information page](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/python2.7-dev).

Edit: and the Mono .exes are just Mono executables. They're distributed in exe form.

Comment: Yep.  In particular, they are used by the distutils `python setup.py bdist_wininst` command to build a self extracting installer for Windows machines (which you can do from Ubuntu for architecture independent packages).

Comment: @JamesHenstridge 
Thanks for the explanation. So they are needed indeed.